# best way to get text from a plain .txt file into a Scroll View

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Can someone please help me out with this I'm actually going nuts!

What is the best way to get text from a plain .txt file into a Scroll View, thats all I need just text.

I've tried so many different solutions but can't get any of them working I was hoping someone could give me a fresh overview.

Comment: When you say Scroll View, do you mean NSScrollView, or just a scrollable text container? (edit - ignore first question, didn't see the uiscrollview tag) Also which part of the process are you having issues with, loading the text from file, or displaying it?

Comment: really just loading it, I have my scroll view set up with a myLabel, its just getting the info into my label I'm having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

Is the file a resource in your application or are you loading it from a network resource? If embedded, you can load it into an  NSString object and then set the text property of the UITextView with that. Something like:

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
NSString *pathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourTextFile" ofType:@"txt"];  
NSString *theText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
myTextView.text = theText;
```

Comment: Just noticed you were asking about scroll view. guess it doesn't matter since you just need to load the text from the file anyway. hope this works.

Comment: Yeah the file is in my resources folder, I will try this out thanks for our help